# Ajax Response Error | just getting error as the response

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

Below is the code for the AJAX File. `alert(cont)` is given the correct result but the problem is with the response. I am just getting error as the response.

```
function updateRadioButton(rating,pid){
    var cont = rating + '-' + pid;
    alert(cont);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        url: TihomAjax.ajaxurl, 
        data: {"action": "tihom_rating_action", "contd":cont},
        success: function(data){ 
            if (data.success) {
                alert("success");
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Code for the `tihom_rating_action function` and other hooks in Wordpress are

```
wp_enqueue_script('tihom_ajax', plugins_url( '/js/tihom_ajax.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_localize_script( 'tihom_ajax', 'TihomAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') ));

    function tihom_rating_action() {         
        echo "hello";
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'tihom_rating_action' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'tihom_rating_action' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript, you're using `"action": "tihom_rating_action"`, but in PHP you're using `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action`. Instead of `my_action` you need to use `tihom_rating_action` as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I corrected the codes as per your points. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using `die()` instead of `wp_die()`? Have you tried debugging the actual ajax response in your browser's developer tools (F12)? What does the response say?

Comment: updated `die()` to `wp_die()` still getting same error. Yes, i have tried there is no error in the ajax code. `alert(cont);` in ajax file gives correct response but the final response from the `tihom_rating_action` is giving an error.

Comment: You're JS is looking for `data.success`, but you're not sending JSON with a success property.